# p2p тунель через свою сеть

Tags: c++, windows, сеть, vpn

Есть клиенты А и B(находятся за NAT), сервер S(выделенный)
А и B могут установить udp канал напрямую, либо tcp через сервер S

клиент A запускает TCP сервер на своей машине, клиент B должен подключиться к этому серверу(такое реализовано в Hamachi)

С помощью чего это реализовать?

Comment: Если вы получаете пакет, то либо его послали по броадкасту, либо конкретно вам. В первом случае вы бессильны, во втором можно все сделать просто через `iptables`.

Comment: Какой iptables? Стоит тег "windows" же.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что частые незначительные изменения текста вопроса приблизят Вас к цели. Если компьютер не является шлюзом (назовем это так) и просто "видит" все проходящие в данном сегменте сети пакеты, то он не в состоянии предотвратить доставку. Пожалуй, Вам стоит расписать задачу вместе с сетевой инфраструктурой поподробнее.

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальная кроссплатформенная библиотека [pcap](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap).

> Позволяет создавать программы анализа сетевых данных, поступающих на сетевую карту компьютера.

Comment: Им можно только снифить пакеты, переадресовывать и изменять не получится, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Не ошибаетесь. он только захватывает, причем копирует пакет к вам. Вы конечно через raw socket сможете сформировать любой пакет какой захотите и послать его (теоретически, хз какие ограничения в windows). Но этим способом вы точно никак не сможете запретить передачу изначального пакета. Думаю надо копать в сторону расширений для фаервола, если они возможны

Comment: @Mike Я бы так не был уверен. PCAP состоит из фиктивного драйвера NDIS который снифит пакеты непосредсвенно с устройства. Ворпрос в том, где он расположен: между устройством и реальным стеком или свой фиктивный стек регистрирует. Ну и собственно ничего не мешает PCAPу фильтр иметь.